# dtrace: use pid provider on multiple libraries simultaneously

Tags: dtrace

This dtrace script will fire every time any function is called in libx by process 12345.

```
dtrace -q -n 'pid12345:libx::entry { printf("probe fired"); }'
```

But what I really want is to detect function calls in several libraries, say libx, liby, and libz... something like:

```
dtrace -q -n 'pid12345:libx,liby,libz::entry { printf("probe fired"); }'
```

Does anyone know if this is possible using the pid provider - or any other provider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [globbing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36846/glggn.html#scrolltoc) in the probe description, e.g.

```
dtrace -q -n 'pid12345:lib[xyz].so::entry { printf("probe fired"); }'
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my own question, but would welcome any other suggestions. The solution I found is to add multiple comma-separated probes:

```
dtrace -q -n 'pid12345:libx::entry, pid12345:liby::entry, pid12345:libz::entry { printf("probe fired"); }'
```